# DBCheckComboBox get values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, devexpress

I have a column that is `NVarChar(MAX)`, it contains text like this: `;0,4,6`

These are the `Flag` values from another table.

A. I set the `EditValueFormat` propertie of the component to `cvfIndices`

B. I put the table values from Table a to a `TcxDBCheckComboBox` component using code like this:

```
Query.Active := True;  
while not Query.Eof do begin
  cxDBCheckComboBox1.Properties.Items.AddCheckItem(QueryCaptionField.AsString);
  Query.Next;
end;
Query.Active := False;
```

C. I assigned a datasource to point to that column I want to hold my value when I select the values in the program the text looks like this in the database: ;0,4,6 how should I query it to find what is selected from SQL Server?

Comment: Well known problem this. Here's one approach, that might help you. Me I'd normalise and throw the csv column in the bin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682188/sql-server-2008-split-sort-and-merge-value

Comment: I agree with Tony. You can however query a string like `',0,4,6,'` with SQL using `POSITION(',' + fieldname + ',', listfieldname) <> 0`.

Comment: Jens 'POSITION' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: This should teach you to never, never use CSV in a database. It's pure evil.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer while using cvfIndices the value saved in the database represents the index of the value in the combobox so you can query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TechCardsData 
LEFT JOIN TechCardsOperations
on 
CHARINDEX(CAST(TechCardsOperations.ID-1 as nvarchar(max)),TechCardsData.OperationsFlags) <> 0
```

and everything works :) hope this helps someone :)

Comment: forgot to mension you need to use RowNumber instead and it works believe me i tried :D

Comment: `CHARINDEX('1', ';10') <> 0` is `True`, so this is a very dangerous solution.

Comment: agreed its a dangerous solution thanks Jens for pointing this out, maybe someone will come up with a better solution.